# Why is IR Transceiver transmitting/receiving rubbish?

Tags: microcontroller, wireless, infrared

I am trying to interface two microcontrollers wirelessly using IR transceivers. The microcontroller I'm using is ATMega164PA running on a 3.3V supply at 8MHz and the transceiver is [TFDU4101-TR3](http://www.vishay.com/docs/81288/tfdu4101.pdf). I am using serial communication for both. When I try to send a character 10 times from one transceiver to another, I get a range of numbers between 255 and 193. Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Even if I send any other character I get the same rubbish.

Also, can I write my own protocol to establish communication between the two devices?

A schematic of my setup is shown below:

[image]

Comment: According to the datasheet, transmitter protection kicks in if a pulse on TX is longer than 50 μs. Can you check the TX data stream with a logic analyzer? I'd guess if your baud rate is any less than 20000 (Hz) then TX protection would cause havoc. You might want to modulate the serial data at 37 kHz (typical IR) so you only get 27 μs pulses.

Comment: This transceiver should not have 37kHz modulation as it's a 115.2kbps IrDA transceiver, not an IR remote receiver.

Comment: try getting useful signals from one to the other, and then just make your own custom bit-banging protocol. This means you are not restricted by the UART hardware, and you can do whatever speed or system works for you, in as simple manner as you want.

Comment: @KyranF, I tried getting one transceiver to transmit and the other one to receive but I am getting data which is of no use. For eg. I receive 255 255 255 192 195..... And so on when I transmit just one character which is 'H'. This is the first time I'm working with Infrared communication and it's not doing what I expected

Comment: @YannVernier, I don't think I can modulate this transceiver as serial will not be fast enough. Also it says on the datasheet that the receiver echos transmitter. What does that mean?

Comment: @aja. I do not have access to logic analyzer. How can I modulate the signal using serial RX and TX lines? It's impossible

Comment: Do you have the circuit setup in the same way as shown in page 6 of the datasheet? IT looks like you can just put TX and RX at up to 115200 Baud rate and it should 'just work'. Shutdown (SD) pin should be grounded (or held low by DIO pin on microcontroller) for normal operation

Comment: @YannVernier True, but the datasheet says it supports "carrier based remote control modes" so that could still be an option. Either way, David will either need to generate and decode IrDA data streams (http://www.actisys.com/article.html) unless an AtMel IrDA library is available, or do his own mod/demod. I'd probably bit-bang as KyranF suggested and make up a protocol. It'll be hard without an analyzer though. I just noticed that the datasheet mentions an RS232 interface module TOIM4232 which might be worth a look.

Comment: I would recommend getting your two microcontrollers communicating via a direct wired connection first. Once that works, replace the wired connection with the IR xcvr setup. This way you have isolated any problem to a smaller portion of the whole system.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like either a baud rate mismatch or a start bit detection problem. Characters between 255 and 193 mean bits 7 and 6 are always set (0b11000000==192), as well as some lower bit (which are earlier in the serial sequence). Remarkably the receiver idles with RXD high while the transmitter should be inactive with TXD low; this combination could cause unexpected behaviour of the start bit, as the AVR transmitter will idle high. Not being familiar with the IrDA signaling standards, I would probably take an oscilloscope to the signal to examine if RXD is simply inverted from TXD.

If we do have inverted polarity behaviour, we expect a transmission like ...1111110dddddddd111111... to turn into ...111111xx0DDDDD00...0001111..., with the first 0 lost as no transmission, the 0 detected as start bit matching the least significant 1 of the transmitted byte, but the stop bit 1 would be inverted marking the framing error. At a later point, the 0 would be detected as a start bit, and eventually the transmitter times out, causing the appearance of a byte with a pattern 11...00 which does not have the frame error detected. All the data bits that are received are inverted and in the wrong position. The xes represent transmitted 0s which go undetected as the transmitter switches from not sending due to too long pulse to not sending because the value is 0. If this is the behaviour, a logic inverter on TXD should solve it.

Atmel's application note [AVR1303](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8104.pdf), Use and configuration of IR
communication module, covers a peripheral meant to talk to this type of transceiver. It should show what sort of signaling is normally used. By the looks of it, the format used is one pulse per 0 bit only, so direct connection to the USART is not the way to go.

Comment: Oh no. You mean direct connection between the transceiver and the micro will not work?

Comment: Depends on your definition of work. You can send things, but the transceiver will only allow short pulses. It's not designed for common UART links.

Comment: So what do you suggest? I cant bit bang UART

Comment: You could abuse the SPI device to transmit pulses; take a look at how lft's VGA demo Craft does the high resolution black and white graphics for an example.

Answer (score 1):

These IrDA transceivers are designed to work within the confines of the IrDA standard, where a typical UART's output is modulated into a 3/16ths-of-a-1-bit encoding scheme (or at some baud rates, simply a cap on the maximum IR illumination time, about 1.6uS i think).  You need an IrDA 'endec' chip (e.g. Microchip MCP2120 & others in this family) at each side of the transmission between the MCUs, or some MCUs have 'IrDA endecs' that can be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The waveform used for IRDA is very different from the usual UART waveform. The UARTs built into many MCUs have an IRDA mode, but it isn't clear whether the ATmega16L does; it isn't mentioned in the [summary datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/2466S.pdf).

Comment: I am using atmega164pa